# What does it mean for to say that $f$ is not continuous...or, what does it mean to not be an open set?

Tags: general-topology

Recall that a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ is continuous means that for any open set $\beta \in B$, $f^{-1}(\beta)$ is open, where $f^{-1}$ is the preimage set.

Say that $f$ is not continuous. Then, that means that there exists some open set $\beta$ in $B$ such that $f^{-1}(\beta)$ is...not open?

What does it mean to be not open? Closed? But open and closed are not necessarily mutually exclusive...

So, what does it mean for a function to not be continuous, properly speaking?

Comment: "not open" means just that...it isn't open.  Taking the usual topology on $\mathbb R$, for example, to say that some subset $S$  of the reals is "not open" means that we can find $s\in S$ such that no open interval about $s$ is contained in $S$.

Comment: @Magdiragdag Fixed!

Comment: Do you understand what open sets are first?

Comment: @Nameless A set $S$ is open if for every $x \in S$, there exists some neighbourhood of $x$, $N(x)$ such that $N(x) \subset S$.

Comment: Do you understand what it means though?

Comment: @Nameless Yeah, so a set is not open if there exists some $x \in S$ such that all $N(x) \cap S^c \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: @user89, well I see you accepted an answer so I assume you understand then. Have fun studying.

Comment: @Nameless Thanks, but where did you hope to go with your point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means exactly what you say: there is some open subset $\beta\subset B$ for which $f^{-1}(\beta)\subset A$ is not open.  The fact that $f^{-1}(\beta)\subset A$ is not open means that there is some $x\in f^{-1}(\beta)$ so that every open neighborhood of $x$ contains points which are not in $f^{-1}(\beta)$.

For instance, consider $f\colon\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R}$ defined by
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix} 0, & x<0\\ 1, & x\geq 0\end{matrix}\right.,
\end{equation}
which you certainly know to be discontinuous.  Then $\beta=(1/2,3/2)\subset\mathbf{R}$ is open, but $f^{-1}(\beta)=[0,\infty)$.  Every open neighborhood of $0$ contains points which are not in $[0,\infty)$, so $[0,\infty)$ is not open.  So $f$ pulls an open set back to a set which is not open, and is therefore not continuous.

Answer (score 3):

As another tack, here's an intuitive notion of what's happening: If $f$ isn't continuous, then there must be a non-open $A$ that maps to an open $B = f(A)$.  Since $A$ isn't open, there must be a point $x \in A$ that is "on the edge": That is, every neighborhood of $x$ contains some point $y \not\in A$, no matter how "small" that neighborhood is.

Now consider the images $f(x)$ and $f(y)$.  We know that $f(x) \in B$, since $B = f(A)$.  But since $B$ is open, that means that there must exist some neighborhood of $f(x)$ that lies entirely within $B$.  And yet, since $y \not\in A, f(y) \not\in B$ (otherwise, $B$ would not be the image of $A$).

This is the basic idea of continuity: No matter how close we want $f(y)$ to be to $f(x)$, we can make $y$ close enough to $x$ to allow that to happen.  But in this case, it's false; there exist points $y$ arbitrarily close to $x$ such that $f(y)$ is not sufficiently close to $f(x)$.

[image]